# How do I increase the limit on the number of open files in NixOS?

Tags: nixos

I'm testing out IPFS on NixOS and I'm seeing errors due to "too many open files" in the `journalctl -u ipfs` logs.  `ulimit -n` shows the limit on the number of open files is set at 1024.  How do I increase the file descriptor limit in `configuration.nix`?

Answer (score 3):

I was able to increase the number of open files by adding the following to `configuration.nix`.

```
  security.pam.loginLimits = [{
    domain = "*";
    type = "soft";
    item = "nofile";
    value = "8192";
  }];
```

After running `nixos-rebuild switch` and `reboot`, `ulimit -n` reported 8192.

More specifically, it's also possible to limit the number of file handles used by the IPFS service by adding the following to `configuration.nix`.

```
services.ipfs.serviceFdlimit = 32768;
```